# CSS condition for a python code

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, flask

So, I'm building a login system using a "numpad". There are four numbers on one row and for rows. One number per row should be selected and those should then be correct for a login. The "numpads" are like this, four rows, four numbers:

```
<div class="numbers-1">
        <a class="num-1 active" href="#">1</a>
        <a class="num-2" href="#">2</a>
        <a class="num-3" href="#">3</a>
        <a class="num-4" href="#">4</a>
</div>
<div class="numbers-2">
        <a class="num-1 active" href="#">2</a>
        <a class="num-2" href="#">3</a>
        <a class="num-3" href="#">4</a>
        <a class="num-4" href="#">5</a>
</div>
<div class="numbers-3">
        <a class="num-1 active" href="#">3</a>
        <a class="num-2" href="#">4</a>
        <a class="num-3" href="#">5</a>
        <a class="num-4" href="#">6</a>
</div>
<div class="numbers-4">
        <a class="num-1 active" href="#">4</a>
        <a class="num-2" href="#">5</a>
        <a class="num-3" href="#">6</a>
        <a class="num-4" href="#">7</a>
</div>
```

Here the numbers selected now would be 1 2 3 4 as the css class for these is "active". jQuery changes the classes. Is it possible to make python check if these are correct? In another words, is it possible to make python "if css class for certain links here is 'active' do something else don't"? Or how do you propose this thing to be done?

The thing looks like this online:
http://cl.ly/image/0T1y3l3I3h22

The code that would be executed if the correct numbers were selected would be just a redirect to the page requiring the login. The python would be this then:

```
def login():
    if ...... # if the css class for the links is not whatever it should be
        error = 'an error message'
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('the_page_requiring_login'))
```

The reason python would be nice would be that I'm using Flask for the site and this code above would be very convenient therefore.

Comment: could you post these numpads? And the python code that needs to be executed?

Comment: Having done some research I believe I could do this with javascript variables and somehow pass them to Flask with JSON. Since jquery already sets the css class to active for the links clicked it could at the same time set a variable or four of them to correspond the choises. Then pass these to Flask somehow and check if they are correct?